# Is it a good practice to be a click function in the same tag as ngFor? Angular and JS

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table and `tr` row.

```html
Is it a good practice for my `Click` event to be the same tag as `*ngFor`? If it's not a good practice, what can I do to improve the code?
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is no problem, or we can use routerLink instead of onClick

```
[routerLink]="['./view', user.id]"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to have the click functionality on the ngFor tag itself. Because you're sending only the user and not the whole array.

Since u used async pipe, am assuming your array is an observable. Just make sure your observable doesn't cause any issues.